# JQuery appendTo not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get some understanding of jQuery. The idea is to append a table row to another table.

```
<table id="temp_table">
   <caption>Empty table</caption>        
</table>

<table id="data_table" style="display:none;">
<caption>Template table</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row2">
       <td>
         <input type="text" name ="t1"/>
       </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<apex:form>
   <apex:commandButton onclick="f2();return false" value="New Entry"/>
<apex:form>
```

JS Code:

```
function f2(){                            
         $("#row2").clone().appendTo("#temp_table tbody"); //Line 2                            
            }
```

The appendTo functionality is not working. 
If I replace Line 1 with `$("#temp_table").append($("#row2"));//Line 1`  then one row gets added and if i keep both Line 1 and Line 2, row gets added each time button is clicked. That is it works for

```
function f2(){                
                $("#temp_table").append($("#row2"));             
                //$("#row2").clone().appendTo("#temp_table tbody");                             
            }
```

However two rows get added on first click, then only one row is added on subsequent clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wrote `appendTo("#temp_table tbody");`

instead of `appendTo($("#temp_table tbody"));`

Comment: It is not working either

Comment: try `appendTo($("#temp_table"));` By the way it's not really saleforce related...

Comment: That worked. Also when I included empty <tbody></tbody> in the temp_table and kept  appendTo($("#temp_table tbody"));  it worked.  Strange why i have to explicitly put an empty <tbody></tbody> for this to work. I have seen code without <tbody> work.

Comment: you don't have to append tbody for this to work, but if you say "I want this to be appended to the tbody" and there is no tbody sure it can't work. But if you append the row to the table, the tbody is not required.